# what are the errors within my code , as it can't change the images with one button?

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

Here is the code I have so far, and all it can do is display the first image however once the button is pressed the image doesn't change and I'm not sure what to do?

```js
var index = 0;
var ImageList = ["Images\sad.png", "Images\happy.png"];

function changeImage() {
  index = index + 1;
  if (index == ImageList.length) {
    index = 0;
    'at this point it is supposed to change the image'
  }
  var image1 = document.getElementById("myImage");
  image1.src = ImageList[index];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeImage()">Change emotions</button>
<img id="myImage" src="Images\happy.png" style="width:200px">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set a global variable containing the reference to the element instead of setting it with every function call.

Another thing - your `index` was initially set to `0` and the default `img` was the image on the second position in array, with index `1`, so with the first function call nothing was happening because the `src` wasn't changed.

```js
var index = 0;
var ImageList = ["http://placehold.it/350x150", "http://placehold.it/150x150"];
var image1 = document.getElementById("myImage");

function changeImage() { 
  image1.src = ImageList[index];
  if (index < ImageList.length-1) {
    index = index + 1;
  } else {
    index = 0;
  }
    
}
```

```html
<img id="myImage" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" style="width:200px">
<button onclick="changeImage()">Change emotions</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must escape your backslash in file paths.

```
var ImageList = ["Images\\sad.png","Images\\happy.png"];
```

your code with changes:

```js
var index=0;
var ImageList = ["Images\\sad.png","Images\\happy.png"]; 
function changeImage(){ 
    index=index+1;
    if(index==ImageList.length){
        index=0; 'at this point it is supposed to change the image' 
    }
    var image1= document.getElementById("myImage");
    image1.src= ImageList[index];
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "changeImage()">Change emotions</button> 
<img id="myImage" src="Images\happy.png" style="width:200px">
```

Comment: Slashes for web content should actually be forward, not backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you had this in the code all along or if you added it for this post, but wrote a comment that was invalid syntax:

```
'at this point it is supposed to change the image'
```

Comments should be like this:

```
// at this point it is supposed to change the image
```

Your slashes in your image paths should be forward and not backslashes as well.

See comments inline with the code for other corrections and explanation:

```js
var index = 0;
// Paths should always use forward-slashes, not back-slashes
var ImageList = ["http://images.clipartpanda.com/apple-clipart-apple5.png",
                 "http://web.utk.edu/~gduscher/images/orange.jpg"]; 

// Get your reference to the image element outside of the function 
// so you don't have to keep getting it every time the button is clicked.
var image1 = document.getElementById("myImage");

function changeImage() { 

  // Increment the index counter by 1
  index = index + 1;  // could just write: index++
  
  // If the index has gone too high, reset it to zero
  if(index == ImageList.length){
    index=0; // You wrote your comment wrong: 'at this point it is supposed to change the image' 
  }
  
  // Set the source of the image
  image1.src= ImageList[index];
}
```

```css
img { width: 50px; }
```

```html
<button onclick = "changeImage()">Change emotions</button> 
<img id="myImage" src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/apple-clipart-apple5.png" style="width:200px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an if statement for toggling between 0 and 1 (assuming you're only going to have two images), you can use a ternary operator:

```
(index === 0) ? (index = 1) : (index = 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the backslashes. What do you use them for?
In javascript the backslashes in strings are for special characters, so when you change img.src = list[index] it will change from Images\happy to Imageshappy

your code working
I'm supposing your images are in a folder called 'Images'.

```js
var index=0;
var ImageList = ["Images/happy.png", "Images/sad.png"]; 
function changeImage(){ 
  index=index+1;
  if(index==ImageList.length){
   index=0;  
  }
  var image1= document.getElementById("myImage");
  console.log(image1);
  image1.src= ImageList[index];
  console.log(image1);
}
```

```html
<button onclick = "changeImage()">Change emotions</button> 
<img id="myImage" src="Images/happy.png" style="width:200px">
```